# How to loosely couple Xamarin forms plugin

Tags: c#, class, plugins, static, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to loosely couple [GeolocatorPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) plugin but I'm struggling to create a static class for it.

```
public static class Geolocator

{
    static IGeolocator geolocation;

    public static IGeolocator Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return geolocation ?? (geolocation = CrossGeolocator.Current);
        }
        set
        {
            geolocation = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:** I would like to access everything from abstractions but noticed that abstractions has no interface :/

`IGeolocator` only has access to a few properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for the plugin:
https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html

Does `CrossGeolocator.Current` not accomplish what you're trying to do?